# Unable to execute a PHP script through a Bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a simple test case setup like so:

```
exec('/path/to/bash/script', $output, $return);
```

That piece of code successfully launches a bash script, which contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec php -q /path/to/php/script.php
```

This is where it fails. The PHP script is never executed, and the browser just keeps waiting for a response, until it results in a 500 error after a couple of minutes.

The PHP script it's trying to run is just one line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q

<?php

    file_put_contents('/path/to/folder/output.txt', 'some text');

?>
```

**A few things worth noting:**

- The Bash script runs the PHP code if I run it through the CLI.
- Everything works just fine on the local server, installed through XAMPP on OS X
- The problem is on the remote server. CentOS with WHM/cPanel installed.
- The files mentioned above have 777 permissions.
- I can't get any clues from the return values in the exec() function because the script ends with a 500 error after 'hanging' for a couple of minutes.

Any ideas?

Comment: is php in the path of the bash that's being invoked? have you try `exec /absolute/path/to/php -q ...`?

Comment: Why on earth are you using PHP to call a bash script which runs a PHP script??

Comment: Why don't you just [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the php script in the other php script? Save yourself a `fork` and two `execs`.

Comment: Possibly related: [PHP exec() not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147643/php-exec-not-working-properly)

Comment: I forgot to add that the Bash script does run the PHP if launched through the CLI. So that means the PHP variables are setup correctly.

@DigitalChris I know it looks ridiculous, but it makes sense in the actual scenario.

Comment: @kojiro Because the actual PHP script that needs to be launched by the Bash script takes a long time to complete and needs to run in the background.

Comment: What about this code would make it run in the background? I think this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I would add "> /dev/null 2>&1 &" to the end of the execute command, so the browser wouldn't need to wait for the script to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to Marc B. The issue was the path to the PHP bin. Even though /usr/bin/php path exists and the php variable was set in the environment, I needed to change both to /usr/local/bin/php. This was the correct path that I found with the PHP_BINDIR constant.