# Kill process with php command

Tags: php, linux, firefox, ubuntu, execute

In ubuntu terminal, I can kill "firefox" with this comand:
`pgrep python | xargs kill`
and it works.

But if I try to execute this comand in php in localhost, with this code:
`exec("sudo pgrep firefox | xargs kill",$output);`
It doesn't work and the output is an empty array.
I've just added "www-data" in sudoers. Other exec comand work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP exec() not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147643/php-exec-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sudo to work You CAN'T have a pipe "|" within the call tha way.

Also the clean way is to write the whole path to a binary, like "/usr/bin/pgrep"

Best way to handle redirections in sudo is to put the whole command in a script
and sudo that.